# Advantage of solving the Fokker-Planck equation over Monte-Carlo simulations

Tags: monte-carlo, parabolic-pde

For a standard Ito process

$$dX_t = \mu(X_t, t) \,dt + \sigma(X_t, t) \,dW_t,$$

the Fokker-Planck or forward Kolmogorov equation gives an equation for the probability density $p ( x , t )$ of the random variable $X_t$,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x, t) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\mu(x, t) p(x, t)\right] + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left[\sigma^2(X_t, t) p(x, t)\right].$$

Starting from some initial density $p(x,t_0)$, which is often chosen as a delta-peak at the current spot, i.e. $p(x,t_0) = \delta(x-x_0)$, it can be used to calculate future distributions, and from these prices of financial instruments through expectation values.

The concept is quite similar to Monte-Carlo simulations -- with the difference that Monte-Carlo tries to approximate the distribution from a series of realizations, whereas Fokker-Planck arrives at the same quantity through a (deterministic) PDE. Thus the question:

**What are the advantages of solving the Fokker-Planck equation over using a Monte-Carlo simulation?**

For example: does it give higher accuracy? Are there relevant quantities which can't be calculated via Monte-Carlo? Are there scenarios where it is preferred over Monte-Carlo in practice? And so on.

I'm also looking for thoughts and a discussion on it, so please feel free to post even if it's not a "complete" answer.

Comment: Accuracy - especially in the tails (4+ sigma events) and speed if can be evaluated using closed form characteristic functions (fourier-cosine expansions are my technique of choice here). If you want to use the FP equation to help estimate conditional expectations of a bivariate process like you find in a stochastic local vol model, it surpasses Monte Carlo approaches hands down in my opinion. Discount all the above if your characteristic function is not closed form or closely approximated by such!

Comment: I would add that finite difference methods really struggle with this initial condition being a Dirac function. That is an advantage of MC and Fourier methods although MC methods rapidly degrade as you push out the time horizon (as your 10,000 paths begin to scatter...)

Comment: Very good points mentioned by James Spencer-Lavan (although I'd say that depending on the time you're willing to spend on variance reduction techniques MC may be quite accurate). One the biggest problem with FD though is that it does not scale well to high dimensions (N>2 stochastic factors) while Monte Carlo does. Similarly capital distributions at discrete dates need to be accounted for via no jump conditions on grid nodes while in Monte Carlo these are handled more naturally. So it really depends on the use case I guess.

Comment: A useful trick: if you've already implemented finite differences for the **backward** Kolmogorov equation, simply replacing the tridiagonal matrices by their transpose will provide you with a finite differences scheme for the **forward** Kolmogorov equation, no additional programming required.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So for now I take accuracy and possibly speed as an advantage of FP, and the curse of dimensionality as the usual disadvantage. Feel free to add more thoughts, I will if I encounter some ;-)

Comment: @AntoineConze: do you have a reference for that? I know that the forward and backward equation are adjoint to each other theoretically, but I was not aware one can exploit that in the numerics.

Comment: @davidhigh: intuitively it can be viewed as a consequence of the forward and the backward equations being adjoint to each other, or alternatively as a consequence of the finite differences scheme for the backward equation being a discrete markov chain for which the discrete forward equation is solved using the transpose of the transition probabilities matrix. https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/pironneau/publi/publications/kolmogorov.pdf

Comment: @AntoineConze: [here](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/p.j.c.spreij/winterschool/slidesGiles2.pdf) is also a presentation of Mike Giles which states the same thing. Still I have some difficulties in understanding -- assumptions to make it work like this are imo (i) vanishing at the boundaries to perform the partial integration and (ii) an accurate numerical representation of the theoretical concepts which I would not take for granted. I just have the feeling that I get something different if I'd use the FP directly (i.e. include all the derivatives of the coefficients). Have you verified that maybe?

Comment: Yes I have checked - empirically - that solving FP directly with FD or solving FP by using the adjoint of the Backward Kolmogorov FD linear operator converge to the same value. 
Also I prefer the adjoint approach because it becomes the discrete FP equation associated with the markov chain that results from the FD applied to the backward equation, so forward and backward pricing of options give exactly the same prices, which is good because forward pricing is mostly used for calibration (e.g. to vanilla options volatility smile) while backward pricing is used for book valuation and greeks.

Comment: @AntoineConze: one thing that puzzles me: consider a function $v_0$ propagated forward one step via $v_1 = exp(L\Delta t) v_0$, where $L$ is the linear operator. Now take a backward step again, for which accoding to your recipe I use the transpose: $v_0 = exp(-L^T \Delta t) v_1 = exp((L-L^T) \Delta t)  v_0$ (the last step holds only if $L$ and $L^T$ commute, which they do if $L$ is diagonalizable). In order to obtain $v_0$ again from the backward step, $L$ has to be skew-symmetric, otherwise taking a forward and and a backward step yields different results. But $L$ is not skew-sym. in general.

Comment: @AntoineConze: so, going one step forward and one step backward again yields the original function only when $L$ is skew-symmetric, which does not hold in general. Where is the error? I would expect the forward and backward equation to be interchangeable?

Comment: With a backward step you are computing an expectation $v_k = E_k[v_{k+1}]$. With a forward step you are computing a distribution $p_{k+1} = \text{Prob}_{k+1}|_{p_k}$. Now assume (with your notations) $p_{k+1} = e^{L\Delta t}p_k$ and set $v_k=e^{L^T\Delta t}v_{k+1}$. Then $p_{k+1} . v_{k+1}=(e^{L\Delta t}p_k) . v_{k+1}=p_k.(e^{L^T\Delta t}v_{k+1})=p_k . v_k$. Thus computing $E_0[v_T]$ using backward or forward algorithm will yield the same value.

Comment: @AntoineConze: Thanks. Yes, this is the adjoint condition, which I knew (e.g. from your paper). The question was more whether there is also a "real" time-reversal possible. For example, for skew-symmetric matrices, the exponential matrix used for the time-evolution becomes an orthogonal matrix, which when going backwards in time is just inverted. In effect, this produces exactly the original function. I just wondered whether this can be achieved here as well.

Answer (score 4):

> As there are many comments but no answer, let me just sum up some of the comments.

## Solving a PDE or doing some probability?

Usually when one wants to solve the SDE they get a distribution for $X$. In the real world though it is often more useful know some of the properties of this distribution, such as its expected value $\mathbb{E}(X)$, or more generally $\mathbb{E}(f(X))$. We know by the Feynman-Kac theorem that solving this expectation (possibly a conditional expectation) also corresponds to solving a PDE. It is then up to you to decide what is easier, solve a PDE with some tricky boundary conditions, or find an expectation with some strange conditional statements? Each has there own advantages and disadvantages, but the bulk of it really boils down to **dimensionality**.

## PDEs can become very nasty very quickly

If we only have one driving Brownian motion and we are solving for a scalar random variable, it is likely best to formulate the problem in its PDE form (where possible), as solving PDEs in 2-dimensions is a pretty easy job for most computers. So unless you have some very nasty boundary conditions this will likely be your best shot. However, in real world applications there do exist many nasty boundary conditions, think Barrier options, Asian options, etc, and these then start to correspond to moving boundary value problems and worse.

## When dimensions become very large

A very simple disadvantage of a PDE solver, is that ultimately it will likely boil down to producing some sort of grid or lattice, and then use finite difference or something similar. Typically you can't solve PDEs in the whole of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and so you consider some volume and put points equidistantly spaced in each dimension. Even with a modest 2 points in each dimension if you have a 50 dimensional SDE to solve (not uncommon in some basket options or if you want to model an index or a set of currency exchanges) then you will require a grid of $2^{50} \approx 10^{15}$ points, which is about a petaflop of data.

However, framing this as a Monte Carlo problem using $N$ random numbers then the error scales as $N^{-1/2}$, which doesn't depend on the problem dimension, and hence this is likely the only feasible way to solve such high dimensional problems.

### Boundary conditions are now easy (easier)

Of course if you've written a Monte Carlo solver and a PDE solver it is quite clear that the first is usually easier. Now implementing any exotic function $f$ is fairly trivial, and this is true for most types of exotic options. There are now some new subtleties about introducing biases from various estimators and schemes but these are usually for the more advanced stuff.

## Calculating Greeks

It should also be said that there are a few simple (and complicated) ways to compute the derivatives (aka Greeks) of these expectations with respect to the SDE parameters. In Monte Carlo you can use the same scheme to simply bump the simulation into giving you a derivative, use likelihood ratio or pathwise sensitivity methods, or you can do more complicated methods such as algorithmic differentiation. Some of these give you some Greeks (nearly) for free. However, as far as I can tell if you want to do the same thing using the Fokker-Planck approach then you have much more awkward PDEs to start solving.

## Accuracy

If the dimensionality is small then the PDEs will likely give you the most accurate answer the quickest, and possibly the only route to a very accurate answer if you need one (without renting out a super computer cluster). However, as noted in the comments by Quantuple, if you have a good bit of knowledge about the problem you can get some very accurate answers with some variance reduction techniques, and cut down the compute time with things such as QMC or MLMC, etc.

## Have you got to code it up?

If you've got to code it up, then without doubt it will probably be much easier to implement a simple Euler-Maruyama scheme as part of a Monte Carlo program. Of course there are exceptions, but I think there are more pitfalls and difficulties in solving PDEs than just producing a ton of random numbers.

## Summary

If the dimensions are small, the SDE not too nasty (think autonomous and Lipschitz), and you're not interested in anything too complicated to do with $p(x,t)$, then maybe go for the Fokker-Planck route. Otherwise it's likely Monte Carlo is a safe bet.

***Disclaimer*** I work a lot with Monte Carlo schemes and less with PDE solvers, so please feel free to add anything I have missed/neglected.

Comment: I upvote your answer but still disagree about what you wrote in the section "When dimensions become very large". The accuracy of Monte Carlo method **does depend** on dimension. You can read [this post](https://www.branchini.fun/posts/monte_carlo_indep/). It's better to say **only**, *for any dimension, the error declines at a rate proportional to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$*. But it is wrong to say *Monte Carlo is independent to dimension* because the error is indeed a function of dimension $D$ and $N$, for example:
$$\text{Error} = f(D)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$$

Comment: In some cases, as in [this post](https://www.branchini.fun/posts/monte_carlo_indep/) for example, the function $f$ can be an exponential function of $D$, which makes the Monte Carlo as inefficient as other numerical methods. Personnally, I already worked on a project that had used the Monte Carlo technique for high dimensional problem, and I must suggest another numerical method because the convergence of MC method is not sufficiently fast.

Comment: @NN2: totally agree with your points. Monte-Carlo throws points in an N-dimensional space and based on these samples tries a numerical quadrature, and that is in general infeasible. The benefit of MC is that it samples these points not randomly, but instead is guided by the stochastic PDE (--which is nice). Still, in general, the higher the dimension, the harder the problem (--and thus the more samples are required).